# file.lastModifiedDate; not work in cordova iphone app

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova

> **file.lastModifiedDate;**
>   Does not work in cordova iphone app(it works finely in Android and other latest browsers).
>   It returns only uploaded time.
>   Pls give a reason for that.
>   Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file.lastModifiedDate; Returns the last modified date of the file. Files without a known last modified date use the current date instead.
And it is not supported in Safari (WebKit).